# Using 1000x WS2811 leds and 5v 60amp Power supply. When do I need to re-inject power?

Tags: power-supply, led-strip

I've been reading a lot about the WS2811 LEDs and how to properly set them up. I've purchased a few thousand of them off of Ebay for various projects because they're so easy to use. So far I've only used a series of 100.

I've seen a lot about the need to re-inject power at certain points throughout the series. Most of these use-cases were using power supplies with low amps.

Forgive me if this is a horribly naive question but if I have a 5v 60 amp power supply will I still need to re-inject to account for a voltage drop or will the higher amperage help maintain voltage?

EDIT:
Most of what I've read says re-injection will be required every 60 LEDs or so. I'm at 300 and I'm not seeing any noticeable difference at the end of the series?

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you put 60 amps through the PCB traces on your LED strip. Hint: it's nothing good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage droop is a result of cable resistance over large runs. Resistance adds up the longer and thinner the cable. And as your current load increases, the voltage you see at one end of the cable will decrease. Basic ohms law. In this case you will see the leds down the line look dimmer and dimmer until they stop lighting up at all.

You reinject power every few meters because you want to bypass the resistance of the cable to offer a path of lower resistance and keep the leds looking even.

Keep in mind the 60 leds or so statement is for basic 12V strips, not the smart 5V strips. Reinject power as you see fit (turn all the leds to full brightness white and eyeball it)

Answer (score 1):

The higher amperage that your supply **can** produce is irrelevant. Ohms law dominates and if the volt drop down a conductor due to the current taken by the LEDs causes the LEDs to get progressively dimmer then you might have to re-inject power at the half way point (assuming you apply power at both ends).

> Most of what I've read says re-injection will be required every 60
>   LEDs or so. I'm at 300 and I'm not seeing any noticeable difference at
>   the end of the series?

It all depends on what current your string is using and what the conductor resistances are. There is no generalism other than things will start to get dimmer as you go down the line.

Comment: Is there any danger in hooking up all 1000 to see the difference at the end if the wires are rated for the amperage?

Comment: Maybe you might blind yourself!

Comment: @Bms85smb Just to be sure, Andy is not actually joking: [you *definitely* can hurt your eyes with extremely intense light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158274/does-staring-at-a-bright-led-light-damage-your-eyes), so be careful when experimenting (wearing sunglasses is not so a bad an idea, really!)